# Cannot add click to only one table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, addition

When I execute the following to add a click function to the cell at the end of A particular row, jQuery adds the click function to all of the rows. What am I missing here please?

og_rownum happens to equal a number 3, not a string, and the nth-child(8) column does exist in the table.

```
$("#game_lister_table tr:eq("+og_rownum+"), :nth-child(8)").click(function(e){  
  alert('here');
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: It would help if you included the relevant HTML. And I'm guessing the part with the comma isn't doing what you think it is.

Comment: No I did not realize that, but it is obviously part of my problem. How can I restrict it to just one row/column in my table please?

Comment: Remove the comma `,` from the selector.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to add a listener to only one row on your table. If thats the case just add id="yourID" to the  tag that you want to manipulate.

Then in jquery, select it with

```
$('#yourID').click(function(e){
//code here
});
```

If you don't know which row needs to be manipulated, and want to choose it programmatically, then try this.

```
$("#game_lister_table tr").click(function(e){
    $(this)...//selects the row that was clicked
})
```

Comment: Hi Eric - thanks, but I have no id on each row, column or cell in my table and need to parameterize the binding. I have other requirements that will have a need for me to parameterize the nth-child() also.

Answer (score 0):

I used to to this code when choosing specific Cell/ Cells in HTML table Like You

```
    $("#game_lister_table tr:eq("+og_rownum+"), :nth-child(8)").click(function(e){  
  alert('here');
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

But I found there is an easy way is to Create Dynamically Id for cell every time you create row or cell you have an Easy way to use JQuery Selector for any (row , cell ,....etc)

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var rowIndex =table.rows.length; 
var row = table.insertRow();
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
cell1.id="whatEver";
cell1.innerHTML = "<input type="text" id="txt'+rowIndex+'" />";
```

then your action came Next

```
 $('#ID').on('click',function(e){});
```

Comment: Hi.. Spooky had the working code. Thanks to all who answered.

Answer (score 0):

Since the closest answer was removed, I'll add this.

Use `"#game_lister_table tr:eq("+og_rownum+") td:nth-child(8)"` to select the element you described.